# Unity - 3d particles, how to vary the alpha?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system, particles

Ok, I have 3d rendered particles here and want to vary the opacity by particle, like dust. Currently, they're all somewhat transparent given the Fade material I assigned.

I dont have the option for color over lifetime:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZQMm.png)

and start color did nothing. I would Ping Pong the material set to the rendered mesh, but this will vary ALL the particles at once.

How can I make some particles be more transparent than others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the "Start color" parameter in your particle system, and set it as "Random between two colors", where the two colors you pick represent the two ends of the range of alpha values you need.

You can find it in the Main module of your particle system :

- https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysMainModule.html